# Angularjs :why controller can not access object properties from service?I really confused

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

```js
angular.module('voteApp').factory('VoteFty', function (VoteRsc, VoteStatisticRsc) {

    var data = {
        vote: {}
    };

    var view = function () {

        VoteStatisticRsc.get({id: 1}, function (resp) {
            data.vote = resp;
        })
    };

    var vote = function (params) {

        VoteRsc.update({id: 1, index: params}, function (resp) {
            alert('ok!');
        })
    };

    view();

    return {
        data: data,
        vote: vote,
        view: view
    }
});

angular.module('voteApp').controller('VoteCtrl', function ($scope, VoteFty) {
  
    console.log(VoteFty.data);  // Object{vote:..}
    console.log(VoteFty.data.vote); // Object{}
}
```

In the console VoteFty.data display it has vote property and its value is absolutely correct,but VoteFty.data.vote is null,that is really strange.

why VoteFty.data.vote is null?I really cant not understand,please help me figure out it,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use factory like this:

```
angular.module('voteApp').factory( 'VoteFty', function () {

    var factory = {};
    var privateVar = 'something';

    factory.data = function(){
        //some code here like return private var ect
        return privateVar;
    };

    return factory;
});
```

And than you can use VoteFty.data();

Comment: It looks like a good way to solute my problem,but i still can not figure out why  VoteFty.data.vote returns me a {},that is really confuse me!

Comment: Because data.vote is an empty object registered at beginning of the factory:var data = {
        vote: {}
    }; Your vote function is private function and has no connection with data. Same name doesn't mean it's the same thing and it will be connected. But you could do: var data = {
        vote: vote
    };

Comment: Is that so?Oh well,it seems very reasonable,so may be it is explorer's trick,let me think it over.Thank you very much!